# Make column bold if other column is blank

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have two columns A and B. Both contain text.
I need value in column B to become bold if correspondent value in column A is blank.

For example:

```
A   B
   bold  
1  one  
2  two  
   bold  
3  three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to combine the conditional formatting with the logical function `=ISBLANK(A1)`.

- [screenshot - Finding the conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX8dH.png)

When the conditional formatting tab is opened change the "Format if..." setting to Custom formula if that's not an accurate translation it's the one found in the bottom of the list.

A little windows pops up and here you are to add the statement `=ISBLANK(A1)`. A1 is the area it checks. Do this for the first row and expand in the sheet editor and it should copy to the rest of your table.

- [Example document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13cPhBdc214Si5MFeajTPtxIypy0Uxa-dOUL0pduk_gQ/edit?usp=sharing)

*I left a schedule with some other formatting in the example as well. You will find a solution of what you asked for in the upper right corner.*

Hope this helps you out :)